# Unity unetweaver exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im getting these two compile errors:

```
UNetWeaver error: Exception :System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\Users\futur\Desktop\Anarchy_TheGame\Anarchy Game\Temp\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00251] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream (System.String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver.Weave (System.String assName, IEnumerable`1 dependencies, IAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver, System.String unityEngineDLLPath, System.String unityUNetDLLPath, System.String outputDir) [0x00041] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\Networking\Weaver\UNetWeaver.cs:1715 
  at Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver.WeaveAssemblies (IEnumerable`1 assemblies, IEnumerable`1 dependencies, IAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver, System.String outputDir, System.String unityEngineDLLPath, System.String unityUNetDLLPath) [0x0006e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\Networking\Weaver\UNetWeaver.cs:1843 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Log:Error(String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:20)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Weaver:WeaveAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1, IAssemblyResolver, String, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/UNetWeaver.cs:1851)
Unity.UNetWeaver.Program:Process(String, String, String, String[], String[], IAssemblyResolver, Action`1, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Weaver/Program.cs:34)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Serialization.Weaver:WeaveUnetFromEditor(String, String, String, String, Boolean)
```

and

```
Failure generating network code.
UnityEditor.Scripting.Serialization.Weaver:WeaveUnetFromEditor(String, String, String, String, Boolean)
```

I have only FPSController Directional Light and Terrain in my project.
FPSController script (First Person Controller) shows:

> The associated script cannot be loaded, please fix any compile errors
>   and assign a valid script.

But there are no errors in this script
How do i fix these errors? I cant run game without fixing them.

Comment: Have you tried running Unity as administrator?

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes

Comment: If running as an administrator haven't worked out try to reimport the whole project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antivirus was blocking Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll

> Solution: Add exception in antivirus for project folder

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue with the Unity versions from `5.1.0f3`. To fix that issues it is recommended to re-import all the assets or restart Unity.

**EDIT:**
This was not fixed as it states on [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/error-appears-in-console-when-deleting-not-fully-created-script?_ga=2.137504304.1845489683.1504277432-1821899929.1497950965)

---

Currently to get rid of this issue is to try re-import the assets or if that's not solving the issue just create a new project and copy and paste the assets back to the new one.

Comment: @MarcinNowak Yes, I just found out that it's still on in the newer version and currently there's no fix within Unity.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: As I've mentioned if re-importing assets won't make it any better then you could try 2 things. 1. Remove firstpass dll, and open up the project again. 2. Make a new project and copy all from the first one.

Comment: Where can i find firstpass.dll?

Comment: It's in <projectpath>\Temp

Comment: I dont have Temp folder. I tried searching for firstpass.dll

Comment: @MarcinNowak Search for `Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll` and try to remove it. If you do not have it then try to remove all metadata from your Unity project